# How to turn a text called out by PHP into a link?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, hyperlink

I'm currently using Wordpress and I have website listings that has link names as titles (eg. www.test.com, www.test2.com)

With this php code, it calls out the name of the website link:

```
<h3 class="list"><a class="h1" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
```

Now that website has a "readmore" button and a "visit website" button. I'd like to turn the "visit website" button into a external link using PHP.

For example, the website listing is called "www.test.com". I'd like to turn the "visit website button" into an external link that will make it go to "www.test.com".

Here is my html code for the "visit website button":

```
<div id="visit">
    <a href="#" id="visit-link">Visit website</a>
    </div>
```

I hope someone can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this instead

`<h3 class="list"><a class="h1" href="http://<?php the_title(); ?>">Visit Website</h3>`

If the_title is a valid URL starting with www (not http://), then it'll work. If they already have http:// in the title, remove that part.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I added the "http://" at the beginning of the "<?php the_title(); ?>" therefore, "http://<?php the_title(); ?>". I have 7 boxes and their names are URLs. Now I tried doing what you mentioned to the "visit site" button. Nice! Thanks again and to everyone who shared their thoughts!

Comment: By the way, if I indicate "2" is this a score or just an descending order for best answers? If this is a higher score, I'll give "2" to you. If its just a descending order thing, I'll give you "1". :)

Comment: glad that worked! the 2 is an indication of how many times my answer was up voted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click a link you are visiting the url specified in href attribute.

For example to create a link, to go to google.com I would do this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
```

So in you case you replace # with your link

```
<div id="visit">
    <a href="#" id="visit-link">Visit website</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Thank you for this advice! but I was hoping to code it in php.. Here is a perfect example of a website that has similar functions as mine: try hovering on the thumbnails and click on the visit site button - http://www.cssdesignawards.com    -->

Answer (score 0):

**code it in php**:All i can think of is this code:

```
<?php echo "<a href='http://www.test.com'>visit site</a>" ?>
```

I guess you are confused by

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

the_permalink(); calls get_permalink(); which finally provides the link.You can see its source code in wp-includes/link-template.php.

Comment: Thanks! This is great but what I am trying to do is to enhance this code to become an external link: <?php the_title(); ?>. This code generates the name of the website listing. For example it generates www.example.com but it is only a plain text and not an external link. Would it be possible to turn it into a link in php? This website is similar to what I am making: http://www.cssdesignawards.com. Try to hover on the thumbnails and they have a button there that makes you visit their website. Thank you!